# JSONException: Not a primitive array?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm having problems with receiving a JSON array from a URL. I have verified that my link is ok, and the correct JSON array is returned, and it even shows in the error message. I am unsure what it means.

Error:

```
04-17 21:34:04.435  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class org.json.JSONArray
04-17 21:34:04.435  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java)
04-17 21:34:04.445  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetSummary.doInBackground(GetStaticData.java:90)
04-17 21:34:04.445  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetSummary.doInBackground(GetStaticData.java:76)
04-17 21:34:04.445  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)
04-17 21:34:04.445  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
04-17 21:34:04.445  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java)
04-17 21:34:04.445  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
04-17 21:34:04.445  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java)
04-17 21:34:04.445  21842-22217/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
```

Code:

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonArrayParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2);
    JSONArray leagueArray = new JSONArray(jsonArray);
    summary.rTier = leagueData.getString("tier");
    summary.rLeague = leagueData.getString("leagueName");
    summary.rRank = leagueData.getString("rank");
    summary.rLeaguePoints = leagueData.getString("leaguePoints");
```

JSON:

```
[{
   "isHotStreak": false,
   "isFreshBlood": false,
   "leagueName": "Udyr's Lancers",
   "isVeteran": false,
   "tier": "GOLD",
   "lastPlayed": -1,
   "playerOrTeamId": "23591778",
   "leaguePoints": 0,
   "rank": "V",
   "isInactive": false,
   "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
   "playerOrTeamName": "NV43",
   "wins": 83
}]
```

This is all being done from within an AsyncTask, so there is no issue there. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: it would be helpful to see the JSON you are trying to fetch

Comment: `JSONArray leagueArray = new JSONArray(jsonArray);` looks suspect

Comment: @meda Added the JSON to my post.

Comment: @dcharms You were right. Changed up my code a bit and it is working as intended.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! I'm going to post an answer of how you could approach this if there were more than one object in your array.

Comment: @dharms sir can you post the answer regarding:how you could approach this if there were more than one object in your array??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pull down a JSONArray with some objects in it. Try doing something like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonArrayParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2);
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject leagueData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String tier = leagueData.getString("tier");
    String leagueName = leagueData.getString("leagueName");
    String rank = leagueData.getString("rank");
    String leaguePoints = leagueData.getString("leaguePoints");

    // Whatever you want to do with these fields.

}
```

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue. It is because of this line:

```
JSONArray leagueArray = new JSONArray(jsonArray);
```

You are basically creating 2 different JSONArrays, the second one is just pointing back to first, but you can't instantiate the second array this way, or it will throw the error. Thus you don't need to do:

```
new JSONArray(jsonArray)
```

just do:

```
leagueArray = jsonArray;
```

On a side note, I think what you meant to do was:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonArrayParser.getJSONFromUrl(url2);
JSONObject leagueObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

Your first result is an Array (denoted by '[]') but the inner child is an object (denoted by '{}')

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

the second JSONArray is pointing back to first, so just do this:

```
JSONArray firstArray = (JSONArray) secondArray;
```

ofc, cast only if you need!

Answer (score 2):

```
JSON ArrayResponse
[
{
    "name" : "Ravi Tamada", 
    "email" : "ravi8x@gmail.com",
    "phone" : {
        "home" : "08947 000000",
        "mobile" : "9999999999"
    }
    },
    {
    "name" : "Tommy", 
    "email" : "tommy@gmail.com",
    "phone" : {
        "home" : "08946 000000",
        "mobile" : "0000000000"
    }
    }
]
```

After getting Response by Volley library in JsonArray(response), don't Primitive response by creating New JSonArray.

Use the following approach its working:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
String email = jsonObject.getString("email");

JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("phone");
String home = jsonObject2.getString("home");
String mobile = jsonObject2.getString("mobile");
```