# Not a primitive array JsonException When i parse JsonArray

Tags: android, arrays, json, okhttp, org.json

Here is the Response i am getting in this format
`[{"id":15395,"firstName":"Real","lastName":"Me","phone":"(555) 455-6666","address1":"9800 Fredericksburg Road ","address2":null,"city":"San Antonio","state":"TX","zip":"78288"}]`

If i parse the response as Json array i am getting JSONException.

Parsing the data as `val jsonArray = JSONArray(response.body()!!)`

but i am getting error as
`Not a primitive array: class okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody`

Here is How i am calling api

```
val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .build()
        val mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json")
        val body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, setPayloadSearch(value))
        val request: Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.etruckingsoft.com/ets/api/driver/searchDrivers")
            .method("POST", body)
            .addHeader(
                "Authorization",
                "----------------"
            )
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build()
        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

Comment: try `val jsonArray = JSONArray(response.body()!!.toString())`

Comment: I tried but i am getting java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: val jsonArray = JSONArray(response.body()!!.string)

Comment: This Works Fine 'val jsonArray = JSONArray(response.body()!!.string)'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONException: Not a primitive array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146141/jsonexception-not-a-primitive-array)

Answer (score 0):

`response.body()` returns a `ResponseBody` object. Due to this you are then calling the [`JSONArray(Object)` constructor](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray-java.lang.Object-) which expects the argument to be a Java array object, and therefore fails with a `JSONException`.

Instead (as mentioned in the comments) you should call [`response.body().string()`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/string/) to get the actual JSON content of the response and then call the `JSONArray(String)` constructor which parses the JSON data.